# Need to delete past employees gmail account with our domain name

Tags: gmail, google-apps-email

I hired an employee to do marketing for me. I gave her an email address related to the business to look more professional. ie Name@businessdomain.com She has now moved on but I worry she still uses the email address we set up for her to steal clients under our business name. How do I delete her email address?

Comment: Or you could just change the account’s password. See [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33319) for details.

Comment: the same tool you used to create a new email address can be used to delete one.

Answer (score 2):

To delete an email account from Google Apps, you can:

1. Go to `www.google.com/a/yourdomain.com` (replacing `yourdomain` with your domain)
2. Login with an administrator user
3. Click on the **Users** item in the menu that appears
4. This will bring up a list of users and you can either:

   - Delete the user account (and you will lose all documents/email/calendars that are associated with that account)
   - Change the account password (you can then login and see any emails, calendars, and documents that have not been deleted)